# How do I pass my mouse event handlers back up to the parent winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, onmousedown

Context:

```
Form / TableLayoutPanel / UserControl
```

Example handler in the user control:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

I want to notify the **Form** that the UserControl intercepted the **OnMouseDown** event and the form needs to know what Point the user had clicked.

How can I acheive this? Thanks!

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024506/how-to-pass-messages-from-a-child-user-control-to-the-parent

Comment: Why don't you subscribe for mouse events of `UserControl` in `Form`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei How do you do that? I ended up using custom event handlers and actions. What you suggest sounds simpler.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Custom Event Handlers or Actions are OK too. But since your `UserControl` has a `MouseDown` event, you can handle that event in your form ad put your custom logic there. Handling that event is as simple as handling `Click` event of `Button` or other events like `Load` of `Form`.